# preg_match not reading results: Delimiter issue?

Tags: php, regex, string, if-statement, preg-match

I have a part of a string. I need to check if it would equal another string when I add a few symbols on. However, my use of delimiters (I believe) is not allowing for the matches to take place.

My IF statement:

```
if (preg_match("{" . "$words[$counter_words]" . "[<]N}", "$corpus[$counter_corpus]"))
```

My corpus:

```
{3(-)D[<]AN}
{dog[<]N}
{4(-)H(')er[<]N}
{4(-)H[<]A}
{A battery[<]h}
```

My partial array is as follows

```
dog
cat
3-D
plant
```

My goal is to match "dog" with "{dog[<]N}" (the [] and {} are delimiters). To try to compensate for this, I glue delimiters to the start and end of the string. Preg_match accepts it, but does not match the two together.

What would be the solution to this? I cannot find or think of a solution. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to escape the special charcters your matching against

Comment: Okay. Would that change "{" to "/{/"? What would "[<]N}" be? "/[<]/N/}/"?

Comment: would it? i would encourage testing it to find out

Comment: Nope.  I am now getting an "Undefined offset: 233358" notice though, just from placing delimiters in front of the [] symbols.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (preg_match("{" . $words[$counter_words] . "\\[<\\]N}", $corpus[$counter_corpus]))
```

`[` and `]` have special meaning in regular expressions.  If you don't want the special meaning you need to escape them, `\[`.  But because this is inside a PHP string, to get a `\` character, you must enter `\\`.

Comment: or use preg_quote()

Comment: Thank you! Would I have to escape } as well?

Comment: The special regular expression characters are: . \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -

Comment: Okay. I tried changing "{" to "\\{", then got delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Comment: In this case, no you don't have to escape the `{` or `}`.  See http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php ; these are not part of your regex but act as delimiters.

Comment: Okay. I am now getting an "Undefined offset: 233358" notice. I just added the delimiters.

Comment: What is the bug here?

Comment: if (preg_match("{" . "$words[$counter_words]" . "\\\[<\\\]N}", "$corpus[$counter_corpus]"))

Comment: @Dagon: `^=!<>:-` are not special character in regex

Comment: i'm not sure what i'm looking at in there, but the manual seems clear. @Toto

Comment: @Dagon: It's the reference for PCRE. Tell me why `<` or `:` or the other ones  are special.

Comment: "^ assert start of subject (or line, in multiline mode)" "{ start min/max quantifier" ...http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.meta.php @Toto all im going on is the php manual. the line you objected to was a direct quote from the preg_quote() page

Answer (score 0):

> I have a part of a string. I need to check if it would equal another string when I add a few symbols on.

To check if a string equals another one, we don't need `preg_match()`; this would do:

```
if ("{{$words[$counter_words]}[<]N}" == $corpus[$counter_corpus])
```

---

If you use `preg_match()`, you have to heed the [PCRE regex syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php):

> When using the PCRE functions, it is required that the pattern is enclosed
>      by delimiters. A delimiter can be any non-alphanumeric,
>      non-backslash, non-whitespace character.
>
> Often used delimiters are forward slashes (*/*), …

The added *symbols* `{` and `}` at the start and end of your string were taken as pattern-enclosing delimiters, while you meant them to be part of the pattern. You have to add actual delimiters:

```
if (preg_match("/{{$words[$counter_words]}\[<]N}/", $corpus[$counter_corpus]))
```

---

Also of interest:

- [Double quoted](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)
- [Variable parsing / Complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex)